# Confused with Android onClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener

There are 2 ways of handling click events.

1. we define it in xml file like this

> ```
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/button1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:onClick="doSomethingMethod"
>     android:text="Click Me" />
> ```

1. we implement onclicklistener on our activity class and do this

> package com.example.buttontest;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{   
Button button;  
Button another;         
@Override   protected void
    onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);        
another = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2); 

button.setOnClickListener(this);

another.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override   
public void onClick(View v) {       
  // TODO Auto-generated
  method stub       
  if(v.getId()==R.id.button1) 
  {             
   Log.d("MYTAG", "First button was clicked");  
  }

  if(v.getId()==R.id.button2)       
   {            
    Log.d("MYTAG", "Second button was clicked");    
   }
 }
```

}

My question why are we making so hard to call a method in 2nd case? What is the difference? And what is the plus point of working with the 2nd case?

If you don't understand the question plz tell me I will try to explain it more clearly.

Thanks.

Comment: android:onClick="doSomethingMethod" do not use this approach because it doesnt support more > Android1.6

Comment: first off, you don't need to cast it as a button to set the onclicklistener. findViewById(R.id.something).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener...); works just fine. secondly, you'll have a hard time adding the onClickListener via XML if you create a view programatically, i.e. on runtime in the java code.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia but it is working perfecting in android 2.3.3 emulator.

Comment: @damian plz tell me the full line "findViewById(R.id.something).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener...);" what is "..." here?

Comment: but you can not sure because not working on ics

Comment: findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do something
            }
        }); - of course you could also simply pass a reference to an object / instante of View.OnClickListener, to make your code more "readable". private View.OnClickListener mClickListener = new View.OnClciklistener() {...}; and then findViewById().setOnClickListener(mClickListener);.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are exactly the same. `android:onClick` was added in API level 4 to make it easier, more Javascript-web-like, and drive everything from the XML. What it does internally is add an `OnClickListener` on the Button, which calls your `DoIt` method.

Here is what using a `android:onClick="DoIt"` does internally:

```
Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DoIt(v);
    }
});
```

The only thing you trade off by using `android:onClick`, as usual with XML configuration, is that it becomes a bit more difficult to add dynamic content (programatically, you could decide to add one listener or another depending on your variables). But this is easily defeated by adding your test within the `DoIt` method.

```
   Button mClickButton1 = findViewById(R.id.clickButton1);
   mClickButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
   Button mClickButton2 = findViewById(R.id.clickButton2);
    mClickButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
  // some where else in your code

   public void onClick(View v) {
      switch (v.getId()) {
          case: R.id.clickButton1 {
                // do something for button 1 click
              break;
            }
        case: R.id.clickButton2 {
            // do something for button 2 click
              break;
              }
       }
  }
```

This way as i explains is neater in his eyes, as all the onClick computation is handled in one place and not crowding the onCreate method. But the downside I see is, that the:

1.views themselves,

2.and any other object that might be located in onCreate used by the onClick method will have to be made into a field.

Even though you define `android:onClick = "DoIt"` in XML, you need to make sure your activity (or view context) has public method defined with exact same name and View as parameter. Android wires your definitions with this implementation in activity. At the end, implementation will have same code which you wrote in anonymous inner class. So, in simple words instead of having inner class and listener attachement in activity, you will simply have a public method with implementation code.

Answer (score 1):

This is better than using onClick in Xml 
Avoid using onclick in xml if your code is so long....

```
            Button b=new Button(getApplicationContext());
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // your code...
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, This is a good way rather than specifing function in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
package com.example.buttontest;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{   
Button button;  
Button another;         
@Override   protected void
    onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   

button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);        
another = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2); 

button.setOnClickListener(this);

another.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override   
public void onClick(View v) {       
  // TODO Auto-generated
  method stub       
  if(v.getId()==R.id.button1) 
  {             
   Log.d("MYTAG", "First button was clicked");  
  }

  if(v.getId()==R.id.button2)       
   {            
    Log.d("MYTAG", "Second button was clicked");    
   }
 } 

}
```

Comment: Here we are not discussing code implementation but trying to get know the efficient way for handling onClick event also the differences.